# Add EXIF Title to PHP Gallery

Tags: php, exif

I have the following code now, and I want to simply add the EXIF Title data where the "CAPTION" text is. How do I do that? I know how to get the data, but I'm not sure how to add it to the "foreach" loop I already have going.

```
<?php
$path = "./images/bettydew/";
$file_array = array ();
readThisDir ( $path, &$file_array );

echo '<ul class="gallery">';
foreach ( $file_array as $file )
{
  if (strstr($file, "png")||strstr($file, "jpg")||strstr($file, "bmp")||strstr($file, "gif"))
  {
    echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="'.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'"/></a></li>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';

  function readThisDir ( $path, $arr )
  {
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) 
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
            {
              if (is_dir ( $path."/".$file ))
              {
                readThisDir ($path."/".$file, &$arr);
              } else {
                $arr[] = $path."/".$file;
              }  
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: SO readers: this question implicitly refers to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981632/php-dynamic-gallery-problem/4981887#4981887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `foreach` loop with this:

```
foreach ( $file_array as $file )
{
  if (strstr($file, "png")||strstr($file, "jpg")||strstr($file, "bmp")||strstr($file, "gif"))
  {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
   $info = exif_read_data($file);           
   echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="'.$file.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="'.$file.'"/></a>'.$info['Title'].'</li>';
  }
}
```

[this code is my answer to Steve's other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981632/php-dynamic-gallery-problem/4981887#4981887)  @Steve - Please try harder.

Comment: I need to, for real! This one is a bit of a rush, but I'm working on it. I just got it to load from a php?name= so that's good for me now :) So much to learn, so little time...  Thanks again (for the precious crack.)